# Asp.net Response.write only working on local requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, global-asax

Within my Global.asax file, I have the following that displays a javascript alert message for application exceptions:

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('" + FixJQuotes(ex.Message) + "');</script>");
Response.Write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>history.back()</script>");
Server.ClearError();
```

If I access the site via `http://localhost/` and generate a purpose made error (hitting a unique index in the database) the application behaves as expected, the browser shows a javascript alert and then goes back a page to show the editing page.

However, if I access the exact same server, but from a different machine, accessing on `http://192.168.1.x/` hitting the same exception just results in my custom error page being displayed with no clue as to any errors

I am doing something wrong/ missing something obvious?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: set <customErrors mode="Off"/>  in the web.config to see the real error.

Comment: Ah! That then shows the javascript alert message.. I guess its still interpreting it as an exception and therefore redirecting off to the error page.